# Why fist line which is a chart aways output，when using 'uniq -f 2' to Ignore the first 2 fields?

Tags: shell, uniq

for example: the file is

```
The
Second one.
Second one.
Second
Third
Third
```

and I use 'uniq -f 1 uniq.txt',
the output is

```
The
Second one.
Second
```

as the syntax, I ignore the first field, and the output should be:

```
Second one.
Second
```

why???!!!!

Answer (score 1):

the result you got is correct, because you used tool `uniq`.

> Note: 'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they are  adjacent.

the line `The` and `Second` are not adjacent.

and for lines:

```
Second
Third
Third
```

it worked, because they are adjacent.

If you change your file, like this:

```
Second one.
Second one.
Second
The
Third
Third
```

your uniq command will give expected result.

That would be the reason you want to know.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!I know the Note:'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.But I still have the question, whether the uniq must output the first line or not.It means that uniq just cache one line data and default to output first line.

Comment: `With no options, matching lines are merged to the first occurrence` so, normally the answer is "yes". @user2098849. but if you have other option, e.g. `-u`, the first line **could** be out of the output.

Comment: but I user uniq -f 2, the 'the' should not output, but it output```

Comment: @user2098849 it should be in output. I think I have explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The term `field` has the same meaning as for `awk`: it refers to a word, bounded with white characters (or begin/end of line). An entire line is called a record. In the context of option `-f` for the command `uniq`, it simply means that you ignore the first columns of each line.

Instead, use `tail` as follows:

```
'uniq -f 1 uniq.txt | tail -n +2'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Best result, always run `sort` before running `uniq` because `uniq` can compare only the adjacent lines.